# Is there a chart of existing Blackberry platform vs. OS vs. Model versions?

Tags: blackberry, platform

Is there a chart of existing Blackberry platform vs. OS vs. Model versions?

Something like:

```
Blackberry Storm, platforms: x.x.x - y.y.y, OS versions: x.x.x-y.y.y
Blackberry Bold,  platforms: x.x.x - y.y.y, OS versions: x.x.x-y.y.y
Blackberry Curve, platforms: x.x.x - y.y.y, OS versions: x.x.x-y.y.y
```

e.t.c

Comment: This is a tough question, because it isn't just a model to an OS; the individual carriers have to upgrade OS versions.  So Rogers may be well behind AT&T in upgrading, for example, so you might be on version x.y.z on Rogers versus x.y+2.1 on AT&T for the same model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blackberry forum is probably the best place to look - see the post here: http://www.blackberryforums.com/rim-software/58404-latest-operating-system-available-each-blackberry-device.html, which may not be the latest of its kind.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

This location on Wikipedia actually has better information:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlackBerry_OS

Answer (score 1):

BlackBerry now has an official page where they keep information pretty similar to this.  Click on each OS version to show which devices are supported.

http://us.blackberry.com/developers/choosingtargetos.jsp

They say the information is updated quarterly.

**Update:** this link has been dead (or redirected to something different) for a while.  Answer maintained here for historical purposes only :(