# On which device/os to test .net web portal?

Tags: asp.net, mobile, blackberry

I am writing web portal for mobile phones using .net framework, I have tested some stuff on 9530(4.7.X) simulator and it has got issue as some of the javascript doesn't work.

I tested the same in 5.X version simulators of blackberry and it works fine, So I am confused on which version to test so that it reaches the maximum audience.

(Javascript is Enabled on the simulators)

Can somebody please guide me on which simulator to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout BlackBerry KB articles to improve your web content support by blackberry:
[Browser Development - Developing Web Content](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe?func=ll&objId=800733&objAction=browse&sort=name)
[Browser Development - JavaScript](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe?func=ll&objId=852943&objAction=browse&sort=name)

I think RIM OS 4.5 version is most popular

See also:
[What market share do each of the BlackBerry models have?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868567/what-market-share-do-each-of-the-blackberry-models-have)
[Which BlackBerry OS version to target for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437044/which-blackberry-os-version-to-target-for)
[What is the best practise in blackberry development for reaching the widest range of smart phones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540550/what-is-the-best-practise-in-blackberry-development-for-reaching-the-widest-range)
[Is there a chart of existing Blackberry platform vs. OS vs. Model versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520816/is-there-a-chart-of-existing-blackberry-platform-vs-os-vs-model-versions)